# Leetcode bug? (Function isn't stopping even after it returns in binary search)

Tags: c++, debugging, computer-science, binary-search

```
class Solution {
public:
    int search(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = nums.size()-1,mid;
        while (b>a){
            mid = (a+b)/2;
            cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<mid<<endl;
            if (nums[mid]==target) {
                cout<<"ret";
                return mid;
            }
            else if (nums[mid]>target){
                b = mid;
            }else{
                a = mid;
            }  
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
```

The output is :

```
Time Limit Exceeded
Stdout:
0 5 2
2 5 3
3 5 4
ret0 5 2
0 2 1
1 2 1
1 2 1
1 2 1
```

and 1 2 1 keeps repeating.
The test case is :
Input: nums = [-1,0,3,5,9,12], target = 9
Output: 4

The function has printed "ret", hence shouldn't it return and stop? I tried this on my pc, works just fine. Is this a bug?
Leetcode didn't give an error when it's either b > a+1 or if instead of b = mid and a = mid, it's b =mid-1 and a =mid+1.

Comment: Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: what is the test case that results in "Time Limit Exceeded" ? Where is the `main` ?

Comment: If you have the input, you can easily create a [mre] with the input hard-coded into the `main` function. Then use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to help you figure out the problem.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: you should not assume a bug before you ruled out a mistake in your code. Try to attach a debugger and see what happens in case when your code loops forever

Comment: FYI:  Assuming the vector is sorted, `auto iter = std::lower_bound(nums.begin(), nums.end(), target);` does all of the work your code attempts to do with the binary search.  Then it's just a matter of taking `*iter` and doing a test on what value it has (which I leave to you as an exercise).

Comment: Side note: Correct type for indices is `std::size_t`, not `int` (unless you want to use -1 as sentinel for invalid indices), albeit admittedly in given case a vector containing more than 2G elements is unlikely...

Comment: I am not checking the condition you've mentioned. This code runs fine in my pc compiler, when i called the search function through main. But leetcode does enter the first if statement which prints ret and returns. Just that function doesn't stop there and it's behavior then is ambigous.

Comment: Get used to the conventional half-open intervals - they are conventional because they are easier, not because older programmers are weird. See [Why numbering should start at zero](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) (Dijkstra, 1982).

Comment: @NITHINSABU [Using std::lower_bound](https://godbolt.org/z/Ecqcnbaoh).

Comment: @NITHINSABU 1) `int b = nums.size()-1` -- If `nums` is empty, this will give erroneous results.  2) `mid = (a+b)/2;` -- This will overflow if `( a + b )` results in a value that overflows an `int`.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you think it's their bug, you are wrong. It's always your bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code gets stuck in an infinite loop.

When `a == 1` and `b == 2` then `mid = (1+2)/2 = 1` which makes your code take the `a = mid = 1` branch and you never reach `a == b`.

The same happens whenever `(a+b)/2 == a`, ie when `a + 1 == b`.

The `ret` in the output is probably due to a second test case run by the online judge. For the first test your code returns a result but it then gets stuck on the second.

Comment: You're right. It does go into an infinite loop for the other test case which doesn't have the target element. Thanks.